# Building with cmake fails in one QtCreator version while it works with another and also with catkin_make from terminal

Tags: c++, cmake, qt-creator, ros, catkin

I'm trying to build my ROS-System. I do have two different QtCreator versions installed. Building from QtCreator 4.5.1 fails, while building from QtCreator 3.5.1 works just fine. The error I get is the following:

```
Running "/usr/bin/cmake /directory/catkin_ws/src/neuromorphic_stereo '-GCodeBlocks -
Ninja'" in /directory/catkin_ws/build.
CMake Error: The source "/directory/catkin_ws/src/neuromorphic_stereo/CMakeLists.txt" 
does not match the source "/directory/catkin_ws/src/CMakeLists.txt" used to generate
cache.  Re-run cmake with a different source directory.
*** cmake process exited with exit code 1.
```

As I said, building the exact same Project from QtCreator 3.5.1 or the terminal works just fine. I already had that problem before and as far as I remember at that time I just deleted the build-directory of my catkin-worksspace and it worked fine. This time this didn't work. I had already been able to build this project from 4.5.1 but I can't figure out what I was doing different, and the error message doesn't help me at all.

Answer (score 0):

Catkin can build project with 2 tools. Catkin-Tools and Catkin make. If i remember correctly old version of Qt use catkin-make to build project [like that](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/commands/catkin_make). But the newest version uf Qt by default use Catkin build tool (btw this can be changed in properties in build section). If you want to work with bouth version of Qt i suggest to change build tool in 4.5.1 properties from Catkin-Tools to catkin make. And you are correct if you want to build project with another tool you need to clean it (or delete build and devel folder by hand)